# Python requests urllib3 simultaneous connection issues

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

Assume you have the following Python code:

```py
for document in client1.stream_documents():
  # process document
  client2.update_document(document)
```

`client1` and `client2` are 2 separate instances of the same class. Their constructors instantiates a separate `requests.Session`s, that is:

```py
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
```

The `stream_documents` function uses `response = self.session.request(... stream=True ...)` and generates documents as they are read from the server in json lines, that is:

```py
for line in response.iter_lines():
    yield json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

Now back to the code in the beginning of this question, the `update_document` gets stuck and gets reset after 30 seconds (or times out if I set a smaller timeout) with the following:

No timeout:

> ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
> File .../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:714, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)

With timeout:

> TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> File .../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:714, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)

If I exhaust the stream completely then do the update, it works with no issues:

```py
for document in list(client1.stream_documents()): # note the list(...)
  # process document
  client2.update_document(document)
```

I'm wrapping my head around it for a few hours with no luck. I tried using `requests.request` directly without the `Session` object as it is mentioned in the official [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/) that it is the session that is responsible for connection pooling with the help of the underlying urllib3 library, but the error messages are still mentioning connection pools in the same exact line.

I also tried following some SO answers to play with the pool size and max pool, but they didn't fix the problem as their defaults are 10 and 10, respectively, and my problem is just a single host with only two connections attempting the same socket at the same time!

What I'm doing wrong? Could that be a bug in the requests library?!

**Update 1:**

I watched the TCP sockets using netstat and verified that each client will establish their own connection. Both will have the ESTABLISHED state but the cause of the problem is still unknown!

[image: netstat showing both sockets]